# DateTime in c# throwing exception Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((dataGridView1.Focused) && (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0))
            {
                dtpInstallment.Location = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false).Location;
                dtpInstallment.Visible = true;
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != DBNull.Value)
                {
                   // dtpInstallment.Value = DateTime.Today;
                   dtpInstallment.Value = (DateTime)dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;

               //     DateTime date = (DateTime)dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
                 //   dtpInstallment.Value = DateTime.Parse(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));


                }
                else
                {
                    dtpInstallment.Value = DateTime.Today;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dtpInstallment.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

> In this datetime is throwing an exception...there is value in dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value..but not able to convert to dtpInstallment.value which is DateTimePicker

Comment: What is inside `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value` ?

Comment: it is taking values from datagridcell..which is taking value of date from database...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the value your are parsing is not on the correct format. Try using `ParseExact`

```
string poop = "2005-12-14 23:12:34";
string currentFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
DateTime poo = DateTime.ParseExact(poop, currentFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ==> you can change the format that matches the current
//                         value of your dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value
```

Comment: How you could possibly assume this ?

Comment: string dt = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        dtpInstallment.Value = date;
Now I'm using this...it again throwing exception...

Comment: @MichaelT from the OP's phrase `there is value in dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value..but not able to convert to dtpInstallment.value which is DateTimePicker` so i assumed that there is a date with an invalid format.

Comment: @user1658556, what is the value of `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value` before the error occured?

Comment: It as string and not DateTime because of this casting is failing

Comment: @John Woo "10/09/2012" this is the value in this field...and in dtpInstalment.value has value  = {10/09/2012 12:37:40}..
but when I write dtpInstalment.value = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value; then it gives compile time error that can't convert object to datetime..

Comment: @user1658556 if *10 is month* try, `string currentFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";` or if *10 is day*, try `string currentFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";`

Comment: Thanx John problem has been solved with this cast..thnx a lot.. dtpInstallment.Value = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());

Comment: but there is one problem left...when ever i click once in cell it traverses this loop twice...? Why is it so? it is calling this event twice.?

Answer (score 1):

The value in the cell is not a valid date. Perhaps try [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) instead. That way you will get a DateTime if it is a valid format and no exception if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the CellContentClick event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
 DateTime dtpInstallment = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
}
```

then use dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit event

Answer (score 0):

Since you check for DBNull.Value, I guess you retrieve the data using a SqlDataSource, and your datetime value really is of type [SqlDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.aspx).